# Ajax - setInterval not triggerd

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

The code below is not triggered as per the interval set in the setInterval. When the page is loaded the first time the result set is returned, but the Ajax script does not run after first time page load.

```html
   <html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1) Create some html content that can be accessed by jquery
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  <h2> Client example </h2>
  <h3>Output: </h3>
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(function getEvent()
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({
   url: 'get_events.php', data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)
   {
     for (var i in rows)
     {
       var row = rows[i];

       var id = row[0];
       var vname = row[1];
       var time = row[2];
       $('#output').append("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname+"<b> time: </b>"+time)
                   .append("<hr />");
     }
   }
 });
  });

$(document).ready(function () {
var run = setInterval(getEvent, 1000);
});

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have looked at all the similar posts in this forum, but I still can't get my function to be triggered by setInterval. Please see my code below. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to wrap your function in `$(...)`; that syntax is only used as shorthand for `$(document).ready(...)`. Remove that and it should work as expected.

Comment: Use console of your browser to debug. You can't develop without using it.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your function is not in the global scope. Setinterval doesn't know about it.

Use `var getEvent = function() { ... }` to declare the function rather than `$` wrapper.

Comment: Two downvotes for right answer. Have you ever heard about win-win?)

Answer (score -1):

By doing this

```
$(function functionName(){/*function body*/})
```

you are passing a function to another function called $. This doesn't create a function called functionName anywhere. So, when you are starting your interval, you are trying to call a function which does not exist.

Remove `$()` from around your function declaration. This will define a function rather than pass it as a parameter.

Comment: `This doesn't create a function called functionName anywhere. ` it is available inside the call.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Yes. jQuery simply runs it once because its authors decided so and that's all. If $ was not jQuery, it could do something else with the passed function, including doing nothing. I know I could have mentioned that it is available in the function's scope and could be accessed via arguments object.